# Matlab Iteratively remove a row of matrix, except for first iteration

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, iteration

I have a matrix that I use to solve a system of equation using ode45. I am iteratively removing one row in a while loop. However, I want the first iteration to 'continue' and not remove any arrow, so that I can compare all my results where one array is removed with the result using initial matrix.

It would look like:

```
while smtg
    A(pos,:)=0 % Do not compute this line the first iteration
    pop=ode45(involving A)
end
```

My real code:

```
countrow=0;
A=randi([0 1], 5, 5);
distrib=sum(A,1);      
while sum(distrib)>5 
    countrow=countrow+1; 
    A(pos,:)=0; % remove one row
    options = odeset('RelTol', 1e-4);
    [t, pop]=ode45(@Diff,[0 MaxTime],[E I],options,n,m, A);
    nbtot =sum(pop(:,n+1:2*n),2);
end
```

I tried to use

```
if countrow==1 % (the first iteration),
    continue;
end
```

but it skips until the second end and not compute nbtot so I'm out of ideas... Any help?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to achieve, so just an FYI: you can actually delete a row from a matrix (thereby reducing its size) by using `A(pos,:)=[];`. This obviously won't solve your problem, but it might be useful independently from your question.

Comment: No, I want the size of my matrix to remain the same, because am plotting the matrix afterwards, which is why I use A(pos:,)=0; but I admit, in any other case, this is the way of doing it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want `A(pos,:)=0; % remove one row` to occur on the first iteration then put it inside an `if` statement like

```
countrow = countrow + 1;
if countrow ~= 1
    A(pos,:)=0; % remove one row
end
```

The [`~=`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/relational-operators.html) symbol in MATLAB is "not equal to". The line `A(pos,:)=0; % remove one row` will now only execute when `countrow` is **not** equal to `1` but all of the other statements within the loop will execute as normal.

---

The keyword [`continue`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/continue.html) will stop the execution of the current loop iteration and proceed to the next loop iteration. All of the statements after a [`continue`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/continue.html) within a loop will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can go with :

```
A(pos,:)=A(pos,:)*(countrow==1);
```